# 64-bit Win-ros sdk?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone supply me with information on when the win-ros sdk for 64-bit might be coming out? We've got some software we need to compile into ros nodes in 64-bit, only on Windows.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39895/64-bit-win-ros-sdk?/) by [khambuch](https://answers.ros.org/users/2755/khambuch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"A very long time" is the only safe answer to this. The very, very first step of genuine Windows support (the new catkin build system) will ship with Groovy. Getting the great majority of the code working will happen...someday!

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1